# Derivative of a norm vs norm of a derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

Consider a vector-valued function of the time, say $$v: \tau\in\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_N.$$
Suppose that for $\tau=t$, the function is equal to the zero vector, i.e. $$v(t)=0_N.$$ Denote as $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_N$ the value of the time derivative of $v$ in $\tau=t$, i.e. $$\dot{v}(t)=\frac{d}{d\tau}v(\tau)|_{\tau=t}=\alpha.$$
Of course we can write that $$||\dot{v}(t)||=||\frac{d}{d\tau}v(\tau)|_{\tau=t}||=||\alpha||.$$
But I wonder if I can say that $$(\frac{d}{d\tau}||v(\tau)||)_{\tau=t} \le ||\alpha||.$$
And if so, why?

Comment: Do you know that the inner product is bilinear? Do you know how to differentiate a bilinear form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $v\neq 0$, note that
$$
2\|v\|\frac{d}{dt} \|v\| = \frac{d}{dt} \|v\|^2=\frac{d}{dt} v\cdot v=2v\cdot \dot\alpha.
$$
It follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\|v\|\leq \|\dot \alpha\|.
$$

If you do not assume $v\neq 0$, it may be that $\| v\|$ is not classically differentiable. Assuming that $v$ is once continuously differentiable, observe however that the set $\{t|v(t)\neq 0\}$ is open with at most countably many connected components (because $\mathbb R$ is second countable), say $\{t|v(t)\neq 0\}=\cup _n I_n$ with $I_n$ disjoint open intervals. If $I_n=(a,b)$, we see from maximality of a component combined with continuity of $v$ that $v(a)=v(b)=0$. It follows that, for any smooth, compactly supported $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$,
\begin{align*}
\int \|v(t)\| \phi'(t) dt&=\int_{\{v\neq 0\}} \|v(t)\| \phi'(t) dt=\sum_n \int_{I_n} \|v(t)\| \phi'(t) dt \\
&= -\sum_n \int_{I_n} \frac{v(t)\cdot v'(t)}{\|v(t)\|} \phi(t) dt= -\int_{\{v\neq 0\}} \frac{v(t)\cdot v'(t)}{\|v(t)\|} \phi(t) dt.
\end{align*}
What we have shown is that $t\mapsto \|v(t)\|$  is weakly differentiable with
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\|v(t)\|=\begin{cases}\frac{v(t)\cdot v'(t)}{\|v(t)\|} &\mbox{ if } v(t)\neq 0,\\
0 & \mbox{ if }v(t)=0.
\end{cases}
$$
Of course, this implies the inequality you propose!

Comment: I understand this, but my problem is just that $v(t)=0$. Does the inequality still hold?

Comment: I dare ask for some additional detail.
a) How do we pass from the third to the fourth term in the equation with the integrals?
b) Do we need to set the value of the "weak" derivative specifically to zero or any other value would be as good?
c) In the problem I am studying, the function "v" may actually be non differentiable in a finite number of points on the time axis. Do you think that this could destroy the argument? (The left and right derivatives always exist and they are both finite.)

Comment: a) We make use of the fact that $v\neq 0$ in $I_n$, so that $\|v(t)\|$ is differentiable, and you can compute the derivative by the chain rule. The step then reduces to an integration by parts, where the boundary terms vanish because $v$ vanishes at the boundary ('$v(a)=v(b)=0$'). b) Setting equal to zero is the safest option, but you can of course change the weak derivative on a measure-zero set if you want. c) No I don't think this is a problem, but it will induce discontinuities of the weak derivative in the non differentiable points.

Comment: In order to allow for finitely many points of non-differentiability, consider simply cutting up the intervals $I_n$ at the points of non-differentiability. When performing the integration by parts, the boundary terms no longer simply vanish, but they do cancel each other, so the end result is the same. However, for the cancellation to occur, $\|v(t)\|$ must be continuous! (Or you need some other similar condition). Otherwise, delta-distributions will turn up.